# Why does the C compiler not warn about malloc size errors?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, malloc

I made a member struct that I assigned in the ViewDidLoad of my iOS app. I used malloc to allocate space for this struct that was then used throughout my class. Like this:

```
self.myData = malloc(sizeof(MyData));
```

Except what I really did was this:

```
self.myData = malloc(sizeof(MyOtherStruct));
```

I accidentally set sizeof() in the malloc call to be a different struct (that isn't the same size). I didn't notice this mistake for a very long time because the app only rarely crashed. An update to the OS caused the crash to happen more frequently.

My question is, why can compiler's not warn about this sort of thing? Is it something compiler's don't know about or is it a design choice to allow users's to malloc whatever size they please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"How can I find this error faster?"

There are a bunch of ways to find the error faster.

### Solution #1

The static analyzer cathes this error.  Press command-shift-B in Xcode.  For example, take the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x { double x; };
struct y { char y; };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct x *p = malloc(sizeof(struct y));
    p->x = 1.0;
    return 0;
}
```

Running the analyzer produces this error for me:

> Result of 'malloc' is converted to a pointer of type 'struct x' which is incompatible with sizeof operand type 'struct y'

### Solution #2

It is recommended to write the code this way instead:

```
self.myData = malloc(sizeof(*self.myData));
```

Just do it this way in the future.  This is not only less error-prone, but it is easier to remember.

### Solution #3

Use a language like Swift or C++ where the language's type system help you avoid this kind of error.  C is less forgiving in many ways.  It was invented in the early 1970s, you just kind of have to accept that if you want to use it, and these kinds of errors are a *major* part of the reason why C++ and Swift even exist in the first place.

### Solution #4

Use a run-time memory bounds checker, like the address sanitizer.  This will detect the error when memory is accessed, not when it is allocated, but it will still give you stack traces for both access and allocation (and free, if the memory has been freed).  Anyone writing C these days should familiarize themselves with the address sanitizer and its friends, tsan, ubsan, etc.

Valgrind also achieves the same effect but the address sanitizer has a better user experience for common use cases.

## Question as asked

The compiler only really gives you errors and warnings for type errors. This isn't a type error, it's a runtime error.  There are a few "likely" runtime errors that the compiler can detect, but they are very few in number.  Things like forgetting to use the return value of `malloc()`... e.g.,

```
void f(void) {
    malloc(1); // warning
}
```

The compiler isn't much better than that.

Again, this is the impetus for newer languages like C++ and Swift, which have type systems which allow you to generate errors when you allocate things incorrectly, and this is also the impetus for static analysis (which is a tough problem).

Comment: "newer languages like C++ and Swift" - on hearing that C++ threw away her walking stick and went skipping off down the street! She'll pay for it tomorrow though, with aching templates and memory faults everywhere :-) [Sorry, your turn of phrase just made me smile, normal service will now resume.]

Comment: Thanks for #2 - That idiom deserve more use amongst learners.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because is not ARC responsability to deal with `malloc()` and even `free()`

The ARC just handle with objects allocated like `[Object alloc]`

In your case, when you do `self.myData = malloc(sizeof(MyOtherStruct));`, that can be interpreted for example with something like this:

```
self.myData = malloc(N*sizeof(MyData));
//what can represents self.myData[0]..self.myData[N-1]
```

For the last, remember when you use `sizeof()`, it will tell you about the size of the type, that you are passing as a paramter, calculated in compile-time.

You can check this [link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/08/alternative-objective-c-object.html) for more information about object allocation

And also check Apple Documentation about [Memory Alloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html)